# Android Nested Tab View, What's the Best Way to Programmatically Design it - Fragments vs Just One Activity/Fragment and refreshing the view

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, nested

I'm about to start building an android app in which I wish to have a nested set of tabs. Lets call the outer layer of the tabs A, B, C & D and the layer within this 1,2 and 3. 1,2 & 3 are more like filters that somewhat change the information that is represented in the view, but not the layout in anyway. The layout between A, B, C & D will change somewhat but again not to drastically.

I was initially planning on having a main activity which then when them use four different fragments to represent A, B, C & D with 1,2 & 3 within being more like buttons than tabs which will just refresh the view with the relevant information when pressed. However, I'm starting to wonder if I should just use one fragment with tabs that are really secret buttons that refresh the view using the same fragment since the view doesn't change that much?

I hope I've explained this well enough, I've gone over this so many times in my head now that I just need some other opinions.

Comment: do you need to use tabs for the "filter" tabs? Could you use another method like an ActionBar spinner, or an ActionBar Action to do it instead? it would save on screen real-estate and should make it easier to implement

Comment: I've already using ActionBar Action, but I haven't considered a spinner. I give it some more thought but initially I feel that the information I wish to represent should have a very quick, easy to see and use way of instantly filtering the view. 

Also the app I want to make has an IOS version and it uses nested tabs. I would like to keep the view somewhat similar between devices. (Don't worry I'm not ripping someone off, I'm doing it for the original author of the IOS version).

Comment: I think the issue with Android is you have to be able to support a wide range of screen sizes and pixel densities. For example the LG L3 II has a 3" screen 240x320 - so with your ActionBar and two sets of tabs you might only be able to display one or two items in a list depending on how large the items were.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll give that a bit more thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `TabBar` for the A,B,C,D tabs, and then buttons inside each tab's fragment for 1,2,3. if you're targeting API 11+ (or you can create a seperate layout for it in res/layout-v11) you can set the style to `?android:attr/buttonBarStyle` for the layout holding the buttons and `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` for the actual buttons to make them look a little nicer (and more like tabs)

Comment: What about A, B, C & D, should they be separate fragments or the same fragment that refreshed (with the relevant info) every time A,B,C or D is pressed. The layout doesn't change much but the information the layout displays will.

Comment: I think it would possibly be cleaner to implement each one as a separate Fragment, but thats just my coding style. It probably comes down to personal preference

Comment: I think I'll do that - Thank you